# Make wide dataframe long with different variable names

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02',
                   '2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02')),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1037, 1037),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2037, 2037),
  resp_A = c(3,1,2,4),
  resp_B = c(2,4,3,1),
  xxx_connect_A = c(6,2,5,3),
  xxx_connect_B = c(5,3,6,2)
)
```

I want to collapse across _As and _Bs to form one column for each variable.

Here is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(rep(c('2001-01-01',
                       '2001-01-02'),4)),
  PID = c(1091, 1091, 2091, 2091, 1037, 1037, 2037, 2037),
  resp = c(3,1,2,4,2,4,3,1),
  xxx_connect = c(6,2,5,3,5,3,6,2)
)
```

I tried this code from a previous stackoverflow answer but it doesn't work as well now because my variables have differing number of underscores.

```
example |> 
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = c(".value", "who"), names_sep = "_")
```

Does anyone know an efficient way to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `names_sep`, you can use `names_pattern` with a regular expression to split the data

```
example |> 
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = c(".value", "who"), names_pattern = "(.+)_([^_]+)$")
#   date       who     PID  resp xxx_connect
#   <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 2001-01-01 A      1091     3           6
# 2 2001-01-01 B      2091     2           5
# 3 2001-01-02 A      1091     1           2
# 4 2001-01-02 B      2091     4           3
# 5 2001-01-01 A      1037     2           5
# 6 2001-01-01 B      2037     3           6
# 7 2001-01-02 A      1037     4           3
# 8 2001-01-02 B      2037     1           2
```

The regular expression looks for the last "_" that's at the end of the string and splits there.

Comment: Could you please let me know the purpose of  `c(".value", "who")`

Comment: @jkatam There's info on the `pivot_loner` help page about that. We split the column name into "(prefix)_(suffix)". Those match up to the values of ".value" and "who". So the part to the left of the "\_" becomes the column name where the value goes and the value to the right of the "\_" goes into a column named "who" in the output